# Is it fine to use 2.4 GHz nRF24l01 modules in commercial products under FCC rules?

Tags: rf, communication, wireless, fcc, nrf24l01

I want to use nRF24l01 modules commercially. But, at the same time, I am aware of some of the FCC rules. I am just curious if someone knows about the regulation and could help me in this. I found [this FCC document](http://transition.fcc.gov/Bureaus/Engineering_Technology/Documents/bulletins/oet63/oet63rev.pdf).

**EDIT:**

My concern is the use of this module indoor/outdoor products as it is necessary to have FCC ID for radiating products. 
I don't want to get FCC certification as it may cost a lot of money. There should be some way (under FCC rules of course) where I can use this module without getting certification.

The product will be used in both indoor and outdoor environment.

Comment: obvious answer is: obviously it's legal, otherwise nordic wouldn't sell many of those! So, what's your question?

Comment: Great. My concern was indoor/outdoor if it is just available to use indoor environments under FCC regulations and not outdoors.

Comment: you didn't ask that at all? So, **edit** your question and ask what you actually wanted to ask, with all the information necessary.

Comment: I just edited. Thank you. I did some reading on this just now. NORDIC sells ICs. Thus, as per the FCC rules,  they do not require to get FCC certification.

Comment: it's possible for someone to take that IC, build a complete working transmitter around it, get it FCC-approved, and sell it to you. I thought **that** is what we're talking about, since you said *nRF24l01 **module***!

Comment: Yes. I am talking about nRF24l01+ modules and not IC. Okay. I don't find any FCC approved modules anywhere on Sparkfun, Adafruit, Amazon, and eBay. They do sell and some people might be using it without FCC approval, may be!

Comment: @user5311361 The answer really depends on which specific nRF24L01 module you are planning to use. Please post the exact part number.

Comment: @DigitalNinja I am planning to use nRF24L01+ module. Its IC specifications are available [here](https://www.nordicsemi.com/eng/Products/2.4GHz-RF/nRF24L01P). From the store, I will be using [this module](https://www.amazon.com/Makerfocus-Wireless-NRF24L01-Antistatic-Compatible/dp/B01IK78PQA/ref=sr_1_2?ie=UTF8&qid=1485896699&sr=8-2&keywords=nrf24l01) in bulk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2.4 - 2.4835 GHz is unlicensed indoors or outdoors. The one caveat is the maximum transmit power allowed fed into an antenna is 30 dBm (1 Watt). The maximum EIRP is 36 dBm (4 Watts). The max output power from the nRF24l01 is 0 dBm so this will not be an issue.

Comment: Thank you so much for the informative answer. I should be able to use nRF24l01+ in commercial products then.